# Why kotlin insist `ret` variable to be initialized?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following function:

```
override fun countForTicket(dbc: SQLiteDatabase, ticketId: Long): Int {
    var ret: Int

    dbc.query(
        TABLE_SECOND_CHANCE_PRIZES, arrayOf("count(id)"),
        "ticket = ?", arrayOf(ticketId.toString()),
        null, null, null
    ).use { c ->
        ret = if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            c.getInt(0)
        } else {
            0
        }
    }


    return ret
}
```

The problem is that in line `return ret` `ret` is underlined with red and when trying to compile it gives me error:

> Variable 'ret' must be initialized

From my point of view it seems that `ret` is always initialized. What am I missing?
Is it because the initialization is happening in a lambda and the compiler cannot guarantee that the variable is initialized?

Comment: @slaw I am able to use it like `var ret = dbc.query...` but the problem is that I don't understand the reason for the error.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it is the built-in kotlin function `use`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler isn't smart enough to know for sure the lambda will be run once, so it can't figure this out for you.

The reason we don't have this problem with many of the standard library higher-order functions is that they utilize contracts, which tell the compiler what they are doing with the lambda that is passed in (such as guaranteeing that the lambda will be called exactly once).

Unfortunately, `Closeable.use()` doesn't specify a contract (possibly because of it re-throwing exceptions?).

But `use` does return the result of calling the lambda, so you could do

```
val ret = dbc.query(...).use { c ->
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        c.getInt(0)
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

Comment: You may tell compiler that you will run it exactly once, using [contracts](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/-contract-builder/calls-in-place.html)(currently experimental).

Comment: @user28434 How would you add that to the standard lib function? Wrap it in another function?

Comment: why not? If your new function wrapper would be inlinable you will get no significant overhead.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler don't allow unsafe variables like that to be returned. A variable must always be something.

In your case, `ret` is initialized inside a lambda. The compiler doesn't know if this lambda is executed or not. If not, `ret` remains in its unsafe state. Throwing a `NullPointerException` at the end.

If you're sure that this variable is always assigned you can look at [lateinit variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables). You can also put a default value to it `var ret = 0` and ommit the else statement.

Comment: Can `lateinit` be used with local variables?

Comment: I use kotlin 1.3.61 and it works with local variables. I don't know with previous versions

Comment: You can't use `lateinit` on primitives.

Comment: They provide `Delegates.notNull()` to get a similar effect for primitives.